# How does Google put the "shine" on the "block all foo.com results" link that appears?

Tags: google

To repro:

1. Go to google and do a search (for example, follow this link to [search for Jeff Atwood](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=jeff%20atwood))
2. Follow the first result.
3. Hit back in Chrome.
4. Observe that the text that appears that says "Block all codinghorror.com results" has a "shine" affect that occurs to draw your eye to it.

This happens on all sites I follow a link from while logged in to Google using Chrome.

How is this achieved?

[I've recorded it here.](http://www.screencast.com/t/nfG9iuK2aEgh)

The HTML from the relevant section:

```
<img src="/images/experiments/shimmer_mask.png" style="position: absolute; 
 top: 64px; z-index: 500; border-top-width: 0px; border-right-width: 0px; 
 border-bottom-width: 0px; border-left-width: 0px; border-top-style: none; 
 border-right-style: none; border-bottom-style: none; 
 border-left-style: none; border-color: initial; left: 228px; ">
```

Comment: What version of chrome are you using? I'm using v12.0.742.91 and I don't see a shine.

Comment: @john other people tell me the same. 11.0.696.77. I just tried to record it and it won't record! It's like an animation effect that goes over the link from left to right, like a white light.

Comment: @Michael - Maybe Google is running some kind of low percentage A/B test on this and you are one of the lucky ones!?

Comment: That would explain why the mask is in a folder called `experiments`. :P

Comment: wait - are you trying to subvert people into blocking Jeff?

Comment: I believe the google +1 has the same using this image http://www.google.com/images/experiments/nav_logo78.png and a transition effect

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I'm not on Google's cool person list, but from your screencast I got the idea. You can do this with a clever combination of `-webkit-background-clip: text` and some gradients (provided you're on a webkit browser). Here's a (messy) demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/N8UjY/3/

Answer (score 7):

The [jQuery textgrad plugin](http://www.si-les-idees-suffisaient.net/jquery/textgrad.html) can do this. Scroll down to the "textscan" header.
This is several years old, though still works; it's just the first to mind. There's a decent chance something more recent exists, and this should at least give you some ideas how to go about searching further.

[Edit: Michael added the HTML snippet while I was writing]
Given that image is positioned absolutely, it's almost definite that they're just using a bit of script to slide it across the associated a(or maybe span tag) for the block link. Which, given the textgrad plugin seems like complicating things a bit.

Answer (score 5):

[Here's a live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SJvVF/) of a CSS-only solution. (WebKit browsers only, click "Run" to replay animation).

**HTML:**

```
<a href="#" class="kob">Block all results from site.com</a>
```

**CSS:**

```
a.kob{
    color:#36C;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-family:arial, sans-serif;
    font-size:13px;    
    -webkit-animation: wipe 3.0s;
    -webkit-mask-repeat:no-repeat;
    -webkit-mask-position: -40px 0;
    -webkit-mask-size: 40px 50px;
    -webkit-mask-image:  -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top,
                        color-stop(0.00,  rgba(0,0,0,1.0)),
                        color-stop(0.45,  rgba(0,0,0,0.6)),
                        color-stop(0.50,  rgba(0,0,0,0.0)),
                        color-stop(0.55,  rgba(0,0,0,0.6)),
                        color-stop(1.00,  rgba(0,0,0,1.0))); 
}

@-webkit-keyframes wipe {
            0% {
                -webkit-mask-position: -40px 0; 
            }
            100% {
                -webkit-mask-position: 330px 0;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the a gradient, and CSS3 animations for this:

```
 background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, from(#000), to(#000), color-stop(0.5, #fff)) 0 0 no-repeat;

@-webkit-keyframes GoogleLikeShine
{
    0%
    {
        background-position:top left;
    }
    100%
    {
        background-position:top right;
    }
}
```

Of course, you can do the same for Firefox with the Mozilla vendor prefix.